# Move strings into another string with enough capacity

Tags: c++11

```
int main() {
   std::string str;
   str.reserve(9999);

   {
      std::string s1("aaa");
      std::string s2("bbb");
      // can both strings s1, s2 be moved to str?
      // for example str should be "aaabbb"
    }

}
```

My question: is it possible to steal the memory of `s1` and `s2` to form a concatenated string of `s1` and `s2` (since it already has enough space for both)?

Comment: the plus operator is costly for multiple concatenations s1 + s2 + s3 ....

Comment: The plus operator is not costly for multiple concatenations in C++11.

Comment: @HowardHinnant can you elaborate more? What I understand is the last two strings will be added in a new string which will be added to the string before returning a new string and so on. I don't see the possibility of using any move operation in the middle after this question. Since you cannot move any of these temps during the add to the returned string. I thought about implementing expression templates which traverse the whole thing and depending on the total size will construct a string then reserve the capacity and the copy everything one time.

Comment: When the left argument of the plus operator is an rvalue it can be appended to and returned as the result.  Thus capacity of the result is transferred from one plus operation to the next and grows geometrically.  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm#string%20Motivation

Comment: But why "steal" the memory if you already have it allocated in `str`? Unless you want to avoid that `.reserve()` or a copy of the two strings into `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the memory used for a `std::string` has to be contiguous, there can't be a way to steal the memory of two independent strings.

From C++14, section 21.4.1/4:

> The char-like objects in a basic_string object shall be stored contiguously. That is, for any `basic_string`
>   object s, the identity `&*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n` shall hold for all values of n such that 0
>   <= n < s.size().

Comment: @mkmostafa: `std::list` has a splice operation, but it probably wouldn't be a good choice because of the amount of memory used per character.

Comment: basically because std::string is a pointer to char and it can't point to two different char pointers (strings at different memory locations)?

Comment: @mkmostafa: That's not entirely accurate, but it isn't a bad way of looking at it.

Comment: can you tell me where was I inaccurate? :)

Comment: @mkmostafa: For example, a `std::string` object may have short strings stored within itself, or other ways of accessing string memory.

Comment: but these short strings would have to be consecutive pointers or not necessarily?

Comment: @mkmostafa: The actual characters of the string have to be contiguous, regardless of how they are accessed.